# Example of surjective inverse system where projections from limit are not surjective

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I am reading "Profinite Groups" by Ribes and Zalesskii and on page 9 it says that the projections of the nonempty inverse limit of a surjective inverse system are not necessarily surjective, but I can't come up with a counterexample. Here written out:

Given an inverse system $\{X_i,\varphi_{ij},I\}$ of topological spaces $X_i$ over poset $I$ with $X\not = \emptyset$ its inverse limit and the $\varphi_{rs}:X_r\to X_s$ surjective for all $s\le r$, this we call a surjective inverse system. Now the projections $\varphi_i:X\to X_i$ don't need to be surjective, they are if all $X_i$ are compact Hausdorff.

I am now looking for an example where the projections are not all surjective. I tried some stuff with taking $X_i = \mathbb R$ and playing with the maps between, but that didnt't work out. I think I found out the "reason" why it can go wrong, namely that we can take a $(x_i)\in X_i$ such that the inverse limit of $\{\varphi_{ji}^{-1}(x_i),\varphi_{jk}',J = \{j\in I |j\ge i\}\}$ ($\varphi_{jk}'$ the restriction) is empty, but I haven't been able to construct a counterexample.

Comment: See William Waterhouse's paper "An empty inverse limit" [Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 36 (1972) p.618] (and add one extraneous point to each $X_\alpha$ because you want the inverse limit to be nonempty).

Comment: This post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158761/tietzes-extension-theorem-for-compact-subspaces shows that $\varphi_{i,j}$ can be even quotient maps between Banach spaces.